# How to add having clause to withCount in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get posts with total amount of comments created before `2022-05-12 23:59:59`. I also have attached timezone filter. I tried the following:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  $base = Post::withCount([
    'comment' => function ($query) {
      $query->select(
        'id',
        'post_id',
        DB::raw('convert_tz(created_at, "UTC", "US/Eastern") as created_at_tz')
      )->having('created_at_tz', '<=', '2022-05-12 23:59:59')->count();
    },
  ]);


  return $base->get();
});
```

I get error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'posts.id' in 'where clause'

select
  count(*) as aggregate
from
  (
    select
      convert_tz(created_at, "UTC", "US/Eastern") as created_at_tz
    from
      `comments`
    where
      `posts`.`id` = `comments`.`post_id`
    having
      `created_at_tz` <= 2022 -05 -12 23: 59: 59
  ) as `temp_table`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You definitely don't need a select when you're using a `withCount`, since it's only going to retrieve the number of comments, not the comments themselves.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
->withCount([
    'comment' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereRaw('convert_tz(created_at, "UTC", "US/Eastern") <= '2022-05-12 23:59:59'));
    }])
...
```

try this and update me with response

I believe that count at the end is not necessary

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as created_at_tz having `created_at_tz` <= ?) as `comment_count` from `posts`' at line 1`